# ng-bootstrap Modal pass additional class to .modal-dialog

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

I am currently using a custom theme inside a angular application where i need to append a additional css class to the "*.modal-dialog*" container, which is inside of *ngb-modal-window*.

According to the documentation (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api) there is only the possibility to pass a class for *ngb-modal-window* itself by using:

```
this.modalService.open(MyModalComponent, { windowClass: 'my-own-styles' })
```

Is there a way to pass a class to the "*.modal-dialog*" container without using jQuery or so?

Comment: ng bootstrap has its own API why you are referring it to as using jQuery.?

by the way, if it's for CSS purpose, you can directly select that element by tag like [ngb-modal-window]

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, i just mentioned it to not get suggestions to set the class by using jQuery. Beyond that, i just want to set/append a class on the specific container and not to have to rewrite the existing styles of the theme.

Answer (score 2):

I've gone through code in `Modal` component in `ng-bootstrap` library and I can't find a pretty solution to do so. Anyway, if you only want to use this class to style some part of this component, you can use class for modal window and select some class which is child of window, i.e.:

**TS:**

```js
{ windowClass: 'window-class' }
```

**SCSS:**

```css
.window-class {
    .modal-dialog {
        // some styles you want to apply
    }
}
```

Also, I don't think it's the good idea to use jQuery with Angular application.

Comment: The class already exists in the theme and has just to be put there. Otherwise i would have to rewrite it. The class contains styles for either left or right positioning of the modal-dialog. Seems like there is no other option then to rewrite the styles.

Comment: @Mario Are styles you're talking about was wrote specially for `ng-bootstrap`?

Comment: The theme was written for bootstrap 4.5.x, everything is looking great so far. The class/styles i would like to apply make the modal appear attached either on the left or right side of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ['examples' section](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) of that documentation.  The secret lies in the top of the component definition:

[image: Component definition with view encapsulation]

To allow the styles to pass through to the component, you need to set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`.

Once you do that in your component definition, your CSS classes will get picked up.  E.g.: `this.modalService.open(MyModalComponent, { windowClass: 'my-own-styles' })`.